# On click of image icon, refer the input type file function in REACT.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Here I have image icon, with edit icon of it. And when I click on edit icon, image input type file is triggered and picking the file same!

But I count get the event.target.file here...

```
<span className='fa fa-edit edit-icon'
    onClick={(e)=>{this.onChangeFile.click(e)}}> </span>

<input type="file" id="file"
    ref={(ref) => this.onChangeFile = ref}
    style={{display: "none"}}/>
```

method:

But I count get the event.target.file here...

```
onChangeFile =(event)=> {
    console.log('event.target.files', event.target.files)
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log('file.....:', file);
    this.setState({file});
  }
```

Here I am looking for the file path in log. 
currenlty it is not calling the method.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues in your code:

- On mount your `onChangeFile` handler will be erased by the ref callback `ref={(ref) => this.onChangeFile = ref}`
- You're not binding any event handler on the `onchange` event of your input.

It seems that what you are trying to do is to replace the ui of the file browser with a nice edit icon.

Html `label` element and its `for` attribute are there to help you.

The following snippet is plain html/js (no react) but will work in your component if you change the plain html `for` attribute for its React counter part `htmlFor` and if you bind the `onChangeFile` handler the jsx way that is

```
    <input
        type="file"
        id="file"
        onChange={this.onChangeFile}
        style={{display: "none"}}
    />
```

Instead of `document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', onChangeFile);`

The refs are not needed here.

So to sum everything up:

- wrap you span icon into a `label` element.
- set the `htmlFor` attribute to the same value as the file input's `id` attribute.
- attach the onFileChange handler to the onChange event of the file input

That's it, the icon will act as your hidden input should.

```js
onChangeFile = (event)=> {
  console.log('event.target.files[0]', event.target.files[0])
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  console.log('file.....:', file);
}

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', onChangeFile);
```

```css
.edit-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #EEAA11;
}
```

```html
<label for="file"><span class='fa fa-edit edit-icon'> </span><label>

<input type="file" id="file" style="display: none;"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <input type="file" id="file" style={{display: "none"}}
    onChange={(e) => this.onChangeFile(e)}/>
    <label htmlFor="file" >
      <span className='fa fa-edit edit-icon'> </span>
    </label>



  onChangeFile = (event)=> {
    console.log('event.target.files[0]', event.target)
  }
```

Here I just bind the lable with input element. 
Made `display:none` for input.
And it works for me.